# Create desktop notifications for windows with .net 6 console app

Tags: c#, .net, notifications

Historically you could use some libraries which let you hook into the UWP dlls which would fire the desktop notification off, but it seems like they do not work in .net 6, so is there some new avenue to do this?

In my scenario I am on a windows 11 computer with .net 6 with a glorified console application, I have tried using `DesktopNotifications.Windows` lib but that just fails to compile saying that you cannot use the WinRT dlls in .net 6.

Comment: If you search on NuGet for "DesktopNotifications" there's some libraries that target .NET 5, which might work for .NET 6.

Comment: Try using WinRT v1.4.1 which is mentioned at bottom of following page : https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/304?force_isolation=true